# Porque essa linha de código me dá erro?

Tags: java, android

Esta linha de código dá me erro na frase `SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY` e impede me de fazer a base de dados. Porque isto está a acontecer?

```
  SQLiteDatabase BaseDados=SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase("BaseDados",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);
```

O erro que dá é o seguinte:

> Error:(16, 54) error: no suitable method found for openOrCreateDatabase(String,int,)
>   method SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(String,CursorFactory,DatabaseErrorHandler) is not applicable
>   (actual argument int cannot be converted to CursorFactory by method invocation conversion)
>   method SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(String,CursorFactory) is not applicable
>   (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>   method SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(File,CursorFactory) is not applicable
>   (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

O código que eu fiz é o seguinte:

```
public class GestorBaseDados {
Context contexto;
SQLiteDatabase BD;
public GestorBaseDados(Context cont) {
    contexto=cont;
    String erro=null;
    try {

  BD=SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase("BaseDados",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);


    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(contexto,"erro "+e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }



}
```

}

Isto é uma classe que vai ter todos os métodos para mexer na base de dados.

Comment: Coloca o erro que ocorreu

Comment: E que erro que dá? Sem a mensagem de erro fica mais dificil.

Comment: Foi este : Error:(16, 54) error: no suitable method found for openOrCreateDatabase(String,int,<null>)
method SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(String,CursorFactory,DatabaseErrorHandler) is not applicable
(actual argument int cannot be converted to CursorFactory by method invocation conversion)
method SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(String,CursorFactory) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(File,CursorFactory) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Comment: nem sequer me deixa compilar, o projeto

Answer (score 2):

Não existe nenhum *overload* para o método [SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase()](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#openOrCreateDatabase%28java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler%29) com essa assinatura.

Use

```
SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase("BaseDados", null);
```

que é o equivalente a

```
SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("BaseDados", null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY).
```

Comment: o método openDatabase cria a base de dados também?

Comment: Cria se for necessário, veja que é passada a flag `SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY`

Comment: tanto o primeiro método que me indicou como o segundo dão me erro

Comment: O mesmo erro? Veja se está a escrever bem a chamada ao método.

Comment: já não é o mesmo é outro para a primeira opção que me indicou vou lhe passar o código

Comment: Você não alterou o código. Substitua `BD=SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase("BaseDados",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);` por `BD=SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase("BaseDados",null);`

Comment: eu já fiz isso, só que quando pus o código, no site alterei para a forma original para as outras pessoas ver como estava. E continua a não dar, eu fiz um toast e ele diz me que não consegue fazer a base de dados.

Comment: Não sei exactamente o que quer fazer mas o normal é usar uma classe derivada de [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) em vez de usar a classe *SQLiteDatabase*. Veja [aqui](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Local-Databases-with-SQLiteOpenHelper) um exemplo de implementação.

Comment: já resolvi o problema tem- se de adicionar um this antes do método  Fica assim:  BD=this.openOrCreateDatabase("BaseDados",CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);